# Firebase Auth with Laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase-authentication

Im trying to develop an app using Flutter which uses OTP to authenticate a user, ive setup Firebase Auth and everything is working fine, the app sends an SMS to the phone number that the user provided, but now im facing a problem with my Laravel based API, how do i login a user after the OTP auth is done ? surely i cant just send a login request tto my API using only his phone number seeing that its very insecure.
Im sure im missing something here and i would like some guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify the identity of the user in your backend code, send their ID token from the client to that backend, and [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) there. Once you've verified the user's identity, you can then decide whether they are authorized for the action they are trying to perform.

Comment: Thank you sir, you have lead me to the solution i was looking for !

Comment: UIDs are an *identification* mechanism, not an authentication mechanism. So it is **not** safe to allow a user to send you a UID and assume they are that user. But if you've gotten the UID from a securely encoded ID token as described in the link in my answer, it is totally fine to use the UID to determine what they're allowed to do. I often start with a hard-coded UID in my server-side code or security rules  like that.

Comment: So basically if i use the token i get after i sign in, and send it with my api call, and verify that token on my server end to determine the user, would that work ?

Comment: Yup. That's pretty much what the Firebase SDKs and backend services themselves do too.

Comment: Thank you, i have successfully finished the process with your help!